# Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories. Replace almost identical categories

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
np.random.seed(3)

s = pd.DataFrame((np.random.choice(['Feijão','feijão'],size=[3,2])),dtype='category')


print(s[0].cat.categories)
print(s[1].cat.categories)
```

As you can see the dataframe is basically two similar strings with one letter in uppercase. What I am trying to do is replace the category 'feijão' with 'Feijão'

When I write the following line of code I get this error

```
s.loc[s[0].isin(['feijão']),1] = s.loc[s[0].isin(['feijão']),1].replace({'feijão':'Feijão'})
```

TypeError: Cannot set a Categorical with another, without identical categories

I was wondering what does this error means, and also I am genuinely curious if filtering the invalid values and replacing them uniquely on the dataframe is the most optimal way of doing this. Should I just use replace without the filter part?

Comment: You can consider NLP for processing similar types of words. In addition, you may want to change all text into with `.upper` or `.lower` to have similar text throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
s.update( s.loc[s[0].isin(['feijão']),1].replace({'feijão':'Feijão'}))
print (s)
        0       1
0  Feijão  Feijão
1  feijão  Feijão
2  Feijão  Feijão
```

Comment: Gosh darnit i did not see that, but question why the error?